# How to copy elements between arrays and at the same time know how many elements were copied?

Tags: c#, arrays

`Array.Copy` does the copy work but won't tell me how many elements were copied. In situations where either array is not large enough so that fewer elements than i asked for were copied, i need to know how many. So is there some API to achieve this, or do i have to do the calculation in my own code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.Copy` will fail if not enough space exists in the destination array. Nothing will be copied in that case. If you think otherwise you must be misinterpreting something.

In any case you have to perform the calculations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy one array into a new one and then look how many items were copied?
This is futile. Array.Copy() will either copy every item, or no item at all. you will get an `ArgumentException` if your destination array is smaller than your source array.
MSDN tells you the following:

> The sourceArray and destinationArray parameters must have the same number of dimensions. In addition, destinationArray must already have been dimensioned and must have a sufficient number of elements to accommodate the copied data.

Or if you use the `Array.Copy Method (Array, Int64, Array, Int64, Int64)` overload you need to have enough space in your target array to accommodate the source array:

> The sourceArray and destinationArray parameters must have the same number of dimensions. In addition, destinationArray must already have been dimensioned and must have a sufficient number of elements starting from the destinationIndex position to accommodate the copied data.

Either way, there is no way that only part of the items get copied, at least not with `Array.Copy`

Answer (score 0):

It'll copy however elements you tell it to.  `Array.Copy()` takes a parameter specifying the number of elements to copy.

You can use the `Length` property of each array to check the size.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, every overload of the [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array.Copy(v=vs.110).aspx) has `length` parameter, so you know how many elements will be copied beforehand.

For example, if we call it like this:

```
Array.Copy(sourceArray, destinationArray, length);
```

then as documentation says: "if `length` is greater than the number of elements in `sourceArray` or `length` is greater than the number of elements in `destinationArray` the `ArgumentException` will be thrown".